# Would this make any difference in the code

Tags: c++, move

I am trying to understand what std::move does and it seems it's just casting to rvalue reference. In this case, the following two pieces of code are equal, right? Even for the second case, we won't be able to call the move constructor. Otherwise the input person will become in-valid after the move. Am I understanding it correct?

```
void setSomething(Person person) {
  localPerson_ = person;
}
```

v.s.

```
void setSomething(Person person) {
  localPerson_ = std::move(person);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it makes difference.

> it's just casting to rvalue reference.

Precisely it converts to *rvalue*. The parameter `person` is an lvalue, `std::move` would convert it to rvalue. For `localPerson_ = person;`, copy assignment is performed; for `localPerson_ = std::move(person);`, move assignment is performed. Put it in another way, we need to use `std::move` explicitly to make it possible to perform move operation. After that what the `person`'s status would be depends on the implementation of `Person`.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nfCaGEMk16l8tx0L)

Comment: Thanks, what if the input is  setSomething(const Person& person) ?

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld: Then `std::move(person)` is illegal; you could only do copy assignment (`const Person&&` is pretty useless). The advantage to accepting by value is that copy elision could mean `person` is initialized in place, and `std::move` allows move construction/assignment, where accepting by `const` reference in the same scenario (where it's called with a temporary) would require full construction followed by copy construction. Worst case for accepting by value and `std::move`ing is a copy construction followed by move construction or assignment, which isn't much worse.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld Then `std::move(person)` would give a `const Person&&` and passed to assignment operator of `Person`. What happens depends on how `Person` is implemented, but commonly we can't move from a `const` object, so the copy assignment operator but not move assignment operator would be invoked.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld I tried a [live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nfCaGEMk16l8tx0L), which might be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The first case calls the assignment operator. `Person` remains valid afterwards.

The second case calls the move assignment operator. `Person` becomes invalid after the move. For some definition of invalid, depending on the move assignment operator code. It should be akin to a default constructed object.